# A series question whose indices involves greatest integer function

Tags: sequences-and-series, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $x$ be a real number and $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ denote the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$. Let $a$ and $n$ be nonnegative integers such that $n\geq a+1$. Prove that

$$ \sum_{k=a}^{n} f(k) - \sum_{k=a}^{n} (-1)^{k} f(k) = 2 \sum_{k=\lfloor{\frac{a+2}{2}}\rfloor}^{\lfloor{\frac{n+1}{2}}\rfloor} f(2k-1).$$

I proved this by considering the situations where $a$ and $n$ takes even or odd values respectively. Are there any other way to show the equation is true? I generally have trouble with series whose indices involves greatest integer function, are there fast techniques to solve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index of summation is ranging as
$$
a \le k \le n
$$

Replace it with its even and odd components
$$
k = 2j - i\quad \left| {\,i = 0,1} \right.
$$

Then for the even component it shall be
$$
\eqalign{
  & i = 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad a \le 2j \le n\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\lceil {{a \over 2}} \right\rceil  \le j \le \left\lfloor {{n \over 2}} \right\rfloor 
\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\lfloor {{{a + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \le j \le \left\lfloor {{n \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \cr} 
$$
and for the odd
$$
\eqalign{
  & i = 1\quad  \Rightarrow \quad a \le 2j - 1 \le n\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\lceil {{{a + 1} \over 2}} \right\rceil  \le j \le 
\left\lfloor {{{n + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\lfloor {{{a + 2} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \le j \le \left\lfloor {{{n + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \cr} 
$$
Note that for the lower bound we shall employ the ceiling and the floor for the upper. Then we can convert the ceiling to floor.

The sum over $k$ of $f(k)$ can be split into the sum over the even and the odd component
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{a\, \le \,k\, \le \;n} {f(k)}  = \sum\limits_{a\, \le \,k\, \le \;n} {\left. {f(k)\,} \right|_{\,k = 2j}  + \left. {f(k)\,} \right|_{\,k = 2j - 1} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{a\, \le \,2j\, \le \;n} {f(2j)}  + \sum\limits_{a\, \le \,2j - 1\, \le \;n} {f(2j - 1)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left\lfloor {{{a + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \le j \le \left\lfloor {{n \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {f(2j)}
  + \sum\limits_{\left\lfloor {{{a + 2} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \le j \le \left\lfloor {{{n + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {f(2j - 1)}  \cr} 
$$
and same for that of $(-1)^k  f(k)$
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{a\, \le \,k\, \le \;n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} f(k)}
  = \sum\limits_{\left\lfloor {{{a + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \le j \le \left\lfloor {{n \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,2j} f(2j)}
  + \sum\limits_{\left\lfloor {{{a + 2} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \le j \le \left\lfloor {{{n + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,2j - 1} f(2j - 1)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left\lfloor {{{a + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \le j \le \left\lfloor {{n \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {f(2j)}
  - \sum\limits_{\left\lfloor {{{a + 2} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  \le j \le \left\lfloor {{{n + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor } {f(2j - 1)}  \cr} 
$$

Now, just subtract the two above to confirm the thesis.

*--- addendum   ----*

Concerning your request on how to transform ceiling <-> floor, consider that
$$
\eqalign{
  & n = 2\left\lceil {{n \over 2}} \right\rceil  + 2\left\{ {{n \over 2}} \right\} = 2q + i\quad \left| \matrix{
  \;n,q \in Z \hfill \cr 
  \,i = 0,1 \hfill \cr}  \right.  \cr 
  & \left\lceil {{n \over 2}} \right\rceil  = \left\lceil {{{2q + i} \over 2}} \right\rceil
  = \left\lceil {q + {i \over 2}} \right\rceil  = q + \left\lceil {{i \over 2}} \right\rceil  = q + i  \cr 
  & \left\lfloor {{{n + 1} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {{{2q + 1 + i} \over 2}} \right\rfloor
  = \left\lfloor {q + {{1 + i} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  = q + \left\lfloor {{{1 + i} \over 2}} \right\rfloor  = q + i \cr} 
$$
and, in general
$$
\left\lceil {{n \over m}} \right\rceil  = \left\lfloor {{{n + m - 1} \over m}} \right\rfloor \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;n,m \in Z \hfill \cr 
  \;1 \le m \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
re. for details to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients).

Comment: How Did you convert the ceiling function to the floor? That is where I stuck actually.

Comment: @BrightChancellor: put an addendum to answer to this

Comment: I got it, thanks.